# Irrelevant lines when printing output file on a remote server

Tags: c++, eclipse

I wrote the following code in a class in a program in c++, using eclipse on a mac mini:

```
int i = 1;
while (i<=10000) {
  data.open("output.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (data.is_open()) {
    double mean = this->mean_fitness();
    if (mean<0.1) {
      cout << "Exit, population is dead";
      exit(1);
    }
    else
      data << i << "\t" << mean << "\n";
  }
  else
    cout << "unable to open output file";
  data.close();
  this->rep_pop(p, p_rev);
  i++;
}
```

mean_fitness is a function that returns a double.
When I run the code on my computer output.txt file looks like this:

> 1   1
>   2   0.99988
>   3   0.99992
>   4   0.99992
>   5   0.9998
>   ...

when I compile the code on my university's server (I think it's a unix machine, but I'm not sure), output.txt file looks like this:

> 65   0.990096
>   1   1
>   66   0.990424
>   2   0.99988
>   318   0.953251
>   67   0.990424
>   3   0.99992
>   4   0.99992
>   5   0.9998
>   319   0.95441

The lines starting with 65, 66, 318, 67, 319 are not supposed to be there (it is running from 1 to 10000 and printed to the left) those numbers return later, at their place but with a different value in the right column.
I should note that at the first time I ran the code on the server I got a "normal" output.txt file.

Comment: Have you tried to remove or clear old `output.txt` before running you program again?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't start the application multiple times at onces? It seems to me there are 3 instances running at the same time...

Comment: Note: It is possible that this problem has been solved.  Someone, possibly the OP, edited the answer anonymously to state "I did run the program multiple times which changed the output file. Thank you." However, this edit was rejected since it should have been an answer (and possibly a comment).

Answer (score 0):

The program was run multiple times in parallel.

Since all instances wrote to the same output file, your result contains lines from every instances. Nothing frightening.